# How to create bottom navigation similar to hotstar with logo at the center?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[This is the UI of hotstar you can see logo at the center how can I design like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9kyc.jpg)

Comment: Logo design is not a programming question, so this is off-topic here. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you use BottomNavigation, it's pretty straightforward.

1. You'll need an XML file in the navigation directory to define what each button links to. It's described in detail here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer
2. Here's the XML that goes in menu directory to define the UI structure:

   ```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_1"
        android:title="@string/some_text"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_2"
        android:title="@string/some_text"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_logo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_logo"
        android:title="@string/some_text"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_3"
        android:title="@string/some_text"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_5"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_5"
        android:title="@string/some_text"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
   ```
3. Here's the stuff you need in your Java Activity to make it all work:

   BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
   NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_in_navigation_directory);
   NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

Here's how I modified the center icon's size (optional):

```
private void enlargeExploreIcon() {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) navView.getChildAt(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            final View iconView = menuView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.navigation_bar_item_icon_view);
            try {
                final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iconView.getLayoutParams();
                final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                // set your height here
                layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, displayMetrics);
                // set your width here
                layoutParams.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, displayMetrics);
                iconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I did like this I get like drawable image is not showing in menu layout it was not allowing me to show logo it was full white it was not allowing coloured image

Comment: So you can't do multicolored images but a tint with a specific color. I added more details in a specific answer

Answer (score 0):

@SatishV the previous answer wasn't letting me format my code. In your Activity XML, the BottomNavigationView exposes a few theming options. This is where you can change the color of your icons:

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:background="@color/white" 
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"  
        app:colorSecondary="@color/black" 
        android:textColorSecondary="@color/black" 
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_states_bottom_nav" 
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

The `colorSecondary` and `textColorSecondary` will modify the default icon and text appearance. The `color_states_bottom_nav` is a selector element so it provides different colors for pressed/unpressed states.